# Running Eclipse from Linux centos 5.3, no item in menu, command line error (eclipse:31981): Gtk-WARNING

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

i am running CentOS release 5.3, and just successfully installed Eclipse, using yum install eclipse-jdt.x86_64. However:

1. i dont see Eclipse anywhere on the GUI menu. (should be in Applications?)
2. If I type  Eclipse on the command line I get the error message
   (eclipse:31981): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this Eclipse installation?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming problem.  I'd consider moving it to http://serverfault.com/ or another SE site.

Comment: Definitely not [sf]. [su], maybe.

Comment: Is your terminal accidentally ssh'ed into a remote box that isn't running a desktop environment?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not trying to run eclipse as root.

Try: `export DISPLAY=0.0` then running eclipse

You can also try editing the run configuration and selecting the `Environment` tab. Then check for a DISPLAY variable and set it to `0.0`, if there is none create one and set it to `0.0`

Comment: Hi eclipse, welcome to stackoverflow. Reviewing answers from new members and modding you up.